# How do I implement an in-place "Add Item" button in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm not sure if there's a name for this particular kind of UI pattern, but I'd like to create a form that looks like:

```
Company Name: _____
...

Employees:

   Name: _____  Title: _____
   Name: _____  Title: _____

   Add New Employee

Save Company
```

I'm creating or editing a company, but embedded in the form are an arbitrary number of "sub-forms" for that company's employees. If I click the Add New Employee button, a new employee sub-form should appear immediately before the button.

I've been away from Rails for a while and I'm still trying to get the hang of how things are done in Rails 3. In the old days, I would've done something like:

```
 button_to "Add Employee", :remote => true, :action => :new_employee_form
```

and then created `new_employee_form.js.erb`, which would contain JavaScript that appends the new sub-form to the list of company employees.

But Rails 3 seems to have changed a lot of the plumbing that makes this work and this solution doesn't work at all.

What's the recommended way to implement this pattern in Rails 3?

Comment: That should work! What does not work?

Comment: Well, it's good to know I'm on the right track at least :) The request doesn't go through as an AJAX request (the whole page reloads) and then I get an exception along the lines of "Can't find template for new_employee_form"

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you require ujs javascript files in application.js, and that you include application.js in your layout.

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui
```

EDIT

Check the resulting html, it should be similar to:

```
<%= button_to "Create", :action => "create", :remote => true %>
# => "<form method="post" action="/images/create" class="button_to" data-remote="true">
#      <div><input value="Create" type="submit" /></div>
#    </form>"
```

method post, class button_to, data-remote true.

Comment: It must be something with the way I'm calling button_to: `<%= button_to "New Employee", :action => :new_employee_form, :remote => true, :confirm =>"fooo" %>`

Comment: `<form action="/company/new_employee_form" class="button_to" data-remote="true" method="post"><div><input type="submit" value="New Employee" /><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="dV/cgzp298v6KdMbGWYsx1zllxq9WOGVsAEZGib9r0I=" /></div></form>`

Comment: Can you look in the HTML head and make sure that all the javascript includes are there, and that they properly load (use Firebug or equivalent).

Comment: What exactly is the problem here? Doesnt it work to add the "New Employee"-form to the existing form or is it a matter of the new form not being submitted by Ajax?

Comment: @Kristian, The new form doesn't get submitted through Ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Remote_true must be set in the html_options part of the button_to parameters: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/button_to . So the following snipped should work:

```
button_to "Add Employee",  {:action => :new_employee_form} , { :remote => true }
```

**Edit:**

Ok, as you just stated, the problem is, that the new form does not get submitted via Ajax. The reason for this is, that you need to attach event handlers to dynamic elements using the ".on" function: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: I tried that before posting and just tried again to double-check - no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Check out these rails casts episodes:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1

http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2

I use this extensively in my rails apps.